# CircuitTikz: Labeling and defining

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use CircuiTikz to draw resistor network circuits. For example, I am using the following latex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}



\begin{circuitikz}
% Node syntax: (X,Y)

%%% From top :
%% 1st row  ==>
% the voltage source and the resistor   
   \draw  (0,3)  to [R=\SI{}{R_H}, o-o, color=red] (3,3);

% resistors connected; lattce point: x=1, y=Ly 

   \draw [R, o-] (3,3) to (6,3);
   \draw [R, o-] (3,3) to (3,0);
   \draw [R, o-o] (3,0) to (3,-3);

% dashed implying many connections
   \draw [dashed] (6,3) to (9,3);

% resistor continuing after dashed line
   \draw [R, -o] (9,3) to (12,3);

% next resistor 
   \draw [R] (12,3) to (15,3); 
    \draw (15,3) to (15,2.5) node [ground]{};



\end{circuitikz}


\end{document}
```

This gives the following output. 
[image]

Now

1) Can I add a text "V" to the top left corner (left of the resistor labelled by R_H) without inserting a new node? In fact, can I add a text at any coordinate without using a node or path?

2) Using coloring and labelling each resistor, can I redifine a circuit element (e.g. the newly defined resistor will always have label R_H and color red)?

3) Is there any alternative way to the labelling `R=\SI{}{R_H}`? I suspect `\SI` is redundant.

4) Can I directly construct resistors in a series instead of mentioning coordinates for them each time?

I apologize for the numbers of questions. But I guess, they all are connected and relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

It's always better to ask separate questions even if the issues are small/minor, because it leads to more canonical answers that are of use to a wide audience. The question titles then also more accurately reflect the contents of the question and eventual answers.

### Question 1:

I suspect you're referring to not creating another *circuit* node, not another TikZ node, but you can place the text as a TikZ `node` (using the `above` key to place it above the circuit node) along the resistor path, like so: `\draw  (0,3) node[above] {V} to[newR] (3,3);`. This snippet contains other elements from the answers to your other questions, so read on below. `:-)`

### Question 2:

You can do this with TikZ styles, which are very powerful. You define a style at the beginning of the `circuitikz` environment like so: `\begin{circuitikz}[newR/.style={R=$R_H$, o-o, color=red}]`. Now the style `newR` is defined with red color, open nodes at both ends, and a resistor labelled `$R_H$`, so any path with this style specified will have these attributes applied. We use the style like this: `\draw  (0,3) to[newR] (3,3);`, which says that the path from `(0,3)` to `(3,3)` shall have style `newR` (I've left out the previously-specified `node` here for illustrative purposes).

### Question 3:

Your suspicion is correct. `\SI{<number>}{<unit>}` is a command for typesetting physical quantities with units. For a resistance `R_H` as a mathematical variable, it might be better to use `$R_H$` to typeset the value in math mode, which is what I've done in my solution here. If the resistor value is to be specified on the diagram, then `\SI` *is* appropriate, and you could use `\SI{330}{\ohm}` to typeset the value.

### Question 4:

There are a number of ways to do this. I have shown two example methods in my solution.

The first method involves using relative coordinates and collapsing multiple `\draw` commands into a single connected chain: `\draw  (3,3) to[R, o-] ++(0,-3) to[R, o-o] ++(0,-3);`. Notice that I moved the style specification onto the `to` command so each segment of the path can have a different style (resistor, capacitor, etc.) and the `++` syntax is used for relative coordinates.

The second method uses relative coordinates again, but now also named coordinates: `\draw [R, -o] (9,3) to (12,3) coordinate (node1);` labels the coordinate at the end of the path as `node1` (you can name coordinates anything you please). Then we can use that location in later `\draw` commands, like so: `\draw (node1) to[R, o-] ++(3,0) coordinate (node2);`, and so on.

### Complete Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american voltages, american currents,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[newR/.style={R=$R_H$, o-o, color=red}]
% Node syntax: (X,Y)

%%% From top :
%% 1st row  ==>
% the voltage source and the resistor   
   \draw  (0,3) node[above] {V} to[newR] (3,3);

% resistors connected; lattce point: x=1, y=Ly 

   \draw [R, o-] (3,3) to (6,3);
   \draw  (3,3) to[R, o-] ++(0,-3) to[R, o-o] ++(0,-3); % method 1 for series resistors

% dashed implying many connections
   \draw [dashed] (6,3) to (9,3);

% resistor continuing after dashed line
   \draw [R, -o] (9,3) to (12,3) coordinate (node1); % method 2 for series connections

% next resistor 
   \draw (node1) to[R, o-] ++(3,0) coordinate (node2); 
   \draw (node2) to ++(0,-0.5) node [ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]